# Problemas com a função realloc() em linguagem C

Tags: c, falha-de-segmentação

Olá, galera! Estou implementando um código para inserir uma espécie de tabela em um ponteiro e realocar memória enquanto a função `add()` está sendo executada, a função `name()` será executada apenas uma vez para definir o nome da tabela.

O erro: ao adicionar dois nomes à tabela, o código executa normalmente, mas quando ultrapasso duas chamadas à função `add()`, ocorre um **segmentation default**.

Exemplo de erro:

```
add(table, "Lucas\n");
add(table, "Vanessa\n");
add(table, "Marcos\n");
```

Código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int name(char *table, char *text)
{
    table = (char *) realloc(table, (strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (table == NULL) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* O nome da tabela é copiado para "table" */
    strncpy(table, text, (strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int add(char *table, char *text)
{
    table = (char *) realloc(table, (strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    if (table == NULL) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Os dados da tabela são concatenados */
    strncat(table, text, (strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *table = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (table == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro ao inicializar o ponteiro!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    name(table, "Nomes:\n");

    add(table, "Lucas\n");
    add(table, "Vanessa\n");

    printf("%s", table);

    free(table);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Desde já, agradeço grandemente! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O erro do seu programa está na utilização do `realloc()`, nesse trecho:

```
// Esse trecho eh da funcao add
table = (char *) realloc(table, (strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Observe:

```
void *realloc(void *ptr, size_t size);
```

A função `realloc()` modifica o tamanho da memória alocada em `ptr` e o novo tamanho é igual a `size`. Quando falo igual estou dizendo que o tamanho anterior não é adicionado ao valor de `size`, logo `realloc()` pode diminuir o tamanho ao invés de aumentar e é isso que ocorre no seu código.

Voltando para esta parte do seu programa:

```
// Esse trecho eh da funcao add
table = (char *) realloc(table, (strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

Ao você utiliza o `realloc()`, o valor realocado para `table` será igual a `(strlen(text) + 1)`.

Considerando o valor de `(strlen(text) + 1)` igual a `50` e `table` igual a `30`, então os bytes realocados serão `50` e não `80`. Quando o programa fizer isto:

```
strncat(table, text, (strlen(text) + 1) * sizeof(char));
```

`table`, que tem uma `string` de `30` bytes, será concatenada a `(strlen(text) + 1)`, que tem uma `string` de `50` bytes, entretanto `table` só pode armazenar `50` bytes e não `80`. Quanto mais valores forem adicionados com a função `add`, mais dados estarão em espaços de memória desconhecidos até que uma hora ou outra um erro ocorrerá.

Para resolver isso basta calcular o tamanho que realmente `table` precisará ter para armazenar a `string` concatenada, desta forma:

```
table = (char *) realloc(table, ((strlen(table)) + (strlen(text) + 1)) * sizeof(char));
```

Agora o tamanho realocado será `(strlen(table))`, que é o tamanho da `string` que já tem nela, mais `(strlen(text) + 1)`, que é o tamanho da nova `string`.

Veja o código funcionado agora: [código](https://ideone.com/UKUOuT).

Comment: Caracaaa, acabei passando por desapercebido! Muito obrigado, mano :D
Realmente eu pensava que a função realloc() unia o tamanho da string alocada anteriormente, mas é errando que aprendemos. Grande abraço, irmão! :)